# Child element not to inherit parent property (not style) in html

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, textarea

```
<div id='outer_div' onselectstart='return false;'>
     <textarea id='txtbx'></textarea>
</div>
```

In the above code, ***txtbx***, will not allow the user to select its content as it is inheriting the property ***onselectstart*** from it's parent div ***outer_div***. Whereas I donot want ***txtbx*** to inherit ***onselectstart*** from it's parent ***div***. How to achieve this in javascript.

I have written a javascript code, that internally makes text selection from the textarea. Hence I cannot just write ***onselectstart ='return true;'*** as I have something else to happen in this case.
I tried the below methods, but none worked

Trial 1:

```
<div id='outer_div' onselectstart='return false;'>
     <textarea id='txtbx' onselectstart=''></textarea>
</div>
```

Trial 2:

```
<div id='outer_div' onselectstart='return false;'>
     <textarea id='txtbx' onselectstart='default'></textarea>
</div>
```

Trial 3:

```
<div id='outer_div' onselectstart='return false;'>
     <textarea id='txtbx'></textarea>
</div>
delete document.getElementById('txtbx').onselectstart
```

**NOTE: This support is required as this code has to run in IE8**

Comment: In which browser? The textarea element doesn't "inherit" events, the selectstart event bubbles up to the div. I tried the your code in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. To get it to work in Safari required `event.preventDefault()`, it didn't prevent anything in Firefox and in both Safari and Chrome I could select text in the textarea but not in the div itself. Why do you want to prevent selection of text in the div?

Comment: BTW, in none of the browsers I tested did the *selectstart* event bubble up from the textarea (though [*the Selection API specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selection-api/#selectstart-event) says it should) and the event does bubble from other elements (e.g. P within the DIV).

Comment: This happens in IE as I have mentioned as note in the questions. I donot want the user to be allowed to select (multiline text selection) the text in the webpage. DIV has other elements as its child along with the textarea